# Axios Keeps setting my content type as multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary When I have JSON data

Tags: node.js, axios

I have tried many things including adding the headers to the request. Still does not work. I have looked everywhere and came here as a last resort.

My main.js (routes)

```
app.post("/timeclock/punchout", async (req, res) => {
 let time = moment().unix();
 let employeeid = req.body.empid2;
 let date = moment().format();
 let comments = req.body.comments;


 return res.send({ error: false, message: "complete punch" });
});
```

my liquid file using jQuery and axios

```
<script>
    toast = siiimpleToast.setOptions({
        container: 'body',
        class: 'siiimpleToast',
        position: 'top|right',
        margin: 15,
        delay: 2,
        duration: 3000,
        style: {},
    })


    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        let empid1 = $("#empid").val()
        let comments1 = $("#comments").val()

        axios.post('/timeclock/punchin', {comments: comments1, empid: empid1}).then(response => {
            if(response.data.error == false) {
                $("#form").trigger('reset')
                toast.success('Punch Successful!')
            } else if(response.data.error == true) {
                toast.alert(response.data.message)
                $("#form").trigger('reset')
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })

    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        let empid1 = $("#empid").val()
        let commentsout1 = $("#commentsout").val()

        axios.post('/timeclock/punchout', {commentsout: commentsout1, empid: empid1}).then(response => {
          if(response.data.error == false) {
                $("#form").trigger('reset')
                toast.success('Punch Successful!')
            } else if(response.data.error == true) {
                toast.alert(response.data.message)
                $("#form").trigger('reset')
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
```

any ideas? I read that it automatically detects the content type. But I cant seem to override it.